# Converting text field with special characters to field with floats in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a dataset with a text field (`"INL_EL"`) containing mix formatted values likes `{92.066}` or `94.461`.

I want to make a new numeric field (`"INL_EL_N"`) containing the above values. Tried to write the text values to the numeric field using field calculator but as it was expected it only worked for values liked `94.461` and returned null for values like `{92.066}`.

Any ideas how it can be achieved?

Comment: You want to have two values in one numeric field or am I misunderstanding? Are you using a data format that supports list types?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: are parens used to indicate negative numbers - ie, (92.066) = -92.066?

Comment: @bugmenot123 - I think the example values are examples of formatting and isn't intended to suggest two values in a single entry. Hopefully the OP will clarify this.

Comment: the {} is used from a water solutions program to indicate that the value is computed and not user defined. As Llaves said the numbers are two different attributes and not one. @BERA gave the correct answer that it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`regexp_substr( "stringfield", '(-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)')`

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-Python

[image]